# c++ future.get() is not blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, promise, future, packaged-task

According to what's written about **future** in "the c++ programming language 4th edition" 
§5.3.5.1 page 120:

> If the value isn’t there yet, our thread is blocked until it arrives.

Meaning that **get()** is a blocking method.

Later in §5.3.5.2 page 122 **packaged_task** is explained, and the following code sample is given:

```
double accum(double* beg, double* end, double init)
// compute the sum of [beg:end) starting with the initial value init
{
    return accumulate(beg,end,init);
}

double comp2(vector<double>& v)
{
    using Task_type = double(double*,double*,double); // type of task
    packaged_task<Task_type> pt0 {accum}; // package the task (i.e., accum)
    packaged_task<Task_type> pt1 {accum};
    future<double> f0 {pt0.get_future()}; // get hold of pt0’s future
    future<double> f1 {pt1.get_future()}; // get hold of pt1’s future
    double* first = &v[0];
    thread t1 {move(pt0),first,first+v.size()/2,0}; // start a thread for pt0
    thread t2 {move(pt1),first+v.size()/2,first+v.size(),0}; // start a thread for pt1
    // ...
    return f0.get()+f1.get(); // get the results
}
```

This makes sense, since according to the quote the following program won't return until the 2 threads in **comp2()** function finished even without calling **join()** on them since the thread that called **comp2()** will wait for the **future**s until they **get()** their value:

```
int main()
{
    vector<double> v {1.1, 8.3, 5.6};
    double res = comp2(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't happen like I thought, and I less I call **join()**
on the 2 threads in **comp2()**, a run-time error will be thrown.

Could someone explain me what am I missing here and why **get()** doesn't block ?

Comment: Whether `get()` blocks is irrelevant (it does). If you have a joinable `std::thread`, you must `join()` or `detach()` it before it's destroyed.

Comment: @T.C. I see, this wasn't explained yet in the book so I didn't know, nor the example included any call to `join()` or `detach()`

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the `get` didn't block?

Answer (score 1):

I've debugged your code with gdb, your runtime error is happening in std::thread destructor. You have to either `detach` or `join` them before they're destructed, e.g:

```
t1.detach();
t2.detach();
```

inside `comp2()`.

This will net your expected behaviour.